# Flutter -- Display image from Firebase -- Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dart

My app can display image from Firebase. But it takes long time. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: The time to download depends on two things: how big the image is and what the bandwidth of your internet connection is. 
After the initial download it can be cached on your device and will load quickly thereafter. Try package CachedNetworkImage to do this for you. Otherwise, you need to reduce the size of the stored image until you get a reasonable download speed.

Comment: How can i reduce the size of stored image in Firestore?

Comment: What I meant was that you store a smaller image on the database . What is the size of the image you have stored at the moment?

Comment: When the app is downloading stuff, it is normal to show a spinner/progress indicator until it completes. You will always have to deal with slow downloads if you are using a remote database/source.

Comment: Okey. Thank you.

Comment: I solved this problem. I used "imageQuality" property in ImagePicker.pickImage().
For example: 

var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);